# How to stop a user from updating the post date

Tags: users, user-roles, date, save-post

I have a custom role, called "dealer". Once they have posted a new post, they cannot delete it. It's important they cannot update the date either, and I'm a little stuck on how to do this. It looks like the old D/M/Y is preserved in the $_POST global, so I thought I'd over write any updated information for the date with this. Check out my code;

```
function rd_dealer_save_post($post_id)
{
$post_author_id = $_POST['post_author'];
//print_r($_POST);
//test if this author is a dealer based on the caps
if(!current_user_can('delete_published_posts'. $post_author_id))
{
    $_POST['mm'] = $_POST['hidden_mm'];
    $_POST['jj'] = $_POST['hidden_jj'];
    $_POST['aa'] = $_POST['hidden_aa'];
    $_POST['hh'] = $_POST['hidden_hh'];
    $_POST['mn'] = $_POST['hidden_mn']; 
} 
print_r($_POST);
//die();
}
add_action('save_post', 'rd_dealer_save_post');
```

Is my action correct? Any thoughts as this doesn't seem to work...

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: What's with the `'delete_published_posts'. $post_author_id`? Get rid of the ID part, and it should do...

Comment: Yeah, should be a comma..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **@t-f** pointed out in his comment to question, you have an error on checking current user capability: `'delete_published_posts'. $post_author_id` simply **doesn't** exist.

After that, for your scope probably is a better hookin the filter `wp_insert_post_data` instead of the action `save_post`: because this one run when the post was already saved / updated, so if something is wrong you have to change and update again.

Hooking `wp_insert_post_data` filter, you can change the data that are being updated **before** update is ran, so this will improve performance.

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'prevent_post_change', 20, 2);

function prevent_post_change( $data, $postarr ) {
  if ( ! isset($postarr['ID']) || ! $postarr['ID'] || current_user_can('delete_published_posts') )
    return $data;
  $old = get_post($postarr['ID']); // old post
  // prevent changing date
  $data['post_date'] =  $old->post_date 
  $data['post_date_gmt'] =  $old->post_date_gmt 
  // prevent sent to trash
  if ( $data['post_status'] == 'trash' ) $data['post_status'] = $old->post_status;
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, Pity I couldn't figure it out myself, but on the plus side, your code works well and I learnt a new hook (wp_insert_post_data). Thanks

Comment: Although, I had to change this piece of code `isset($postarr['ID']` because the ID is 0 before a new post is published, so I did `$postarr['ID'] == 0`

Comment: @Dan good catch. I've edited my answer, mantaining `! isset($postarr['ID'])` and adding `|| ! $postarr['ID']`

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea. != 0 is ok, but !isset is better I think. Thanks again for your help on this one.

Comment: Without `! isset($postarr['ID'])` even the `$postarr['ID'] == 0` check in the if will output a notice if the `$postarr['ID']` is not defined at all. Can this ever happen? I'm not sure, but better be sure ;) @Dan